# Using search element inside header element

Tags: html, w3c-validation

The [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) gives an error when I use a search element inside a header element. But the [spec page](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-search-element) shows an example with the search element in the header element.

I tried to validate the example, but it also gives the same error.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <title>FOo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <search>
                <form action="search.php">
                    <label for="query">Find an article</label>
                    <input id="query" name="q" type="search">
                    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
                  </form>
            </search>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

> ```
> Error: Element search not allowed as child of element header in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
> From line 8, column 13; to line 8, column 20
>           <search>↩     
> Contexts in which element search may be used:
>     Where flow content is expected.
> Content model for element header:
>     Flow content, but with no header or footer element descendants.
> ```

The error mentions search element can only be used *where flow content is expected* and that header element has *flow content model*. Why is this still invalid then?

Comment: Probably a bug in the validator then; or perhaps not timely updated to reflect changes in the specification that might have happened over time. Try a different one, like https://validator.nu

Comment: @CBroe It is also showing the same error. I believe w3 validator also uses the nu one.

Comment: It's an open issue already reported to the W3C. https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/1569

Comment: @Rob Thanks. So in the end it's a validator bug not bad usage.